# Regex to replace all substrings in text

Tags: javascript, regex

how can I remove all substring here :

> "{SiteName}: Hello, {FirstName}. lallalalallala
> {some other text}
> {Hook some text (USD)}"

Which starts with `{Hook`. What I tried so far is:

```
mystring.repalceAll('{Hook [A-Z\-0-9\s]{1,}}', '')
```

Obviously the regex is not correct but can't really handle it.

Comment: Use `mystring = mystring.replace(/\{Hook [^}]+}/g, '')`

Comment: Backslashes must be doubled. Also, it is not `repalceAll` but `replaceAll`. The text you want to remove also contains `()`, but your character class does not match these chars. And you need a regex literal here, like `.replaceAll(/{Hook [^{}]+}/g, '')`

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to capture the substring between the curly brackets, then you can use this:

```
{Hook.+}
```

Regex will literally match `{Hook` in the original string, and then an unlimited amount of any character (`.+`) until the next curly bracket (`}`).

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/rGcNGP/1)

Comment: Use a non-greedy quantifier or `[^}]+`. Otherwise it matches until the *last* `}`, not the next one.